# Mac Thingsboard Docker - Unable To Connect To Cassandra

Tags: docker, cassandra, thingsboard

I am trying to launch the Thingsboard Docker images in Mac.
I am following the Thingsboard installation for Docker in Mac.
I am running a single node cassandra instance as a docker image locally and the cassandra instance is up and running.

`admin@C02P111XG3QDMBP b2b-order-service (migration) $ cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>`

When I launch the Thingsboard Docker image, then the ThingsBoard application fails to launch as it is unable to connect to cassandra.
Below are the docker container logs for ThingsBoard.

`` admin@C02P111XG3QDMBP installation $ docker logs 8f11b6e0605a
Selecting previously unselected package thingsboard.
(Reading database ... 25169 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /thingsboard.deb ...
Adding group `thingsboard' (GID 102) ...
Done.
Unpacking thingsboard (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up thingsboard (1.4.0-1) ...
Wait for cassandra db to start...
Wait for cassandra db to start...
Wait for cassandra db to start...
Wait for cassandra db to start...
Wait for cassandra db to start...
Wait for cassandra db to start... ``

Please help me with this issue, as it will help to get started with ThingsBoard.

The contents of docker-compose.yml is as mentioned below.

```
version: '2'

services:
  tb:
    image: "thingsboard/application:1.4.0"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "1883:1883"
      - "5683:5683/udp"
    env_file:
      - tb.env
    environment:
      - ADD_SCHEMA_AND_SYSTEM_DATA=${ADD_SCHEMA_AND_SYSTEM_DATA}
      - ADD_DEMO_DATA=${ADD_DEMO_DATA}
    volumes:
      - "${HSQLDB_DATA_DIR}:/usr/share/thingsboard/data/sql"
    entrypoint: /run-application.sh
  cassandra:
    image: "cassandra:3.11.2"
    ports:
      - "9042"
      - "9160"
    volumes:
      - "${CASSANDRA_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/cassandra"
  zk:
    image: "zookeeper:3.4.10"
    ports:
      - "2181"
    restart: always
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.6"
    ports:
    - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - "${POSTGRES_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

The Cassandra instance is running on MAC host and the docker container for thingsboard is running on same MAC host.

Comment: Can you please paste here the docker-compose.yml you are using for the Thingsboard installation (or link to the directions you are using)? Can you also tell me the Docker command you used to start the Cassandra container?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson - Thanks for your reply, I have updated the question with contents of docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2):

Seems the Docker container was not able to resolve the localhost of the MAC VM host. So I replaced the CASSANDRA_HOST=host.docker.internal and it was able to connect to cassandra running on localhost on host MAC VM.